# Why is there an alignment bigger than a word?

Tags: alignment, cpu

Ok I understand that storing a data aligned to a CPU word sized chunks increase the speed of accessing it. But those chunks are normally 16, 32 or 64bit, why there are other aligment values like 128bit or 256bit? I mean there aren't any processors using such large registers in PC's anyway. I supose this have something to do with the CPU cache? Also I have seen such alignments in secondary storage too (but there they are actually much more large - 10240bit for eg.).

Comment: tumbleweed badge, thank you people!

Answer (score 1):

Many processors *do* have 128-bit SIMD registers (e.g., x86 SSE registers, ARM Neon registers, MIPS SIMD Architecture registers); x86 AVX extends SSE registers to 256 bits and AVX-512 doubles the size again.

However, there are other reasons for desiring larger alignments. As you guessed, cache behavior is one motive for using larger alignments. Aligning a larger data structure to the size of a cache line (commonly 64 bytes for x86, usually not smaller than 32 bytes in modern systems) guarantees that an access to any member will bring the same other members into the cache. This can be used to reduce cache capacity use and miss rate by placing members that are frequently used (a.k.a., hot) or which are commonly used at about the same time together in what will be the same cache block.

E.g., consider the following structure accessed with a cache having 32-byte cache blocks:

```
struct {
int64_t hot1; // frequently used member
int64_t hot2; // frequently used member
int64_t hot3; // frequently used member
int64_t hot4; // frequently used member
// end of 32-byte cache block if 32-byte aligned
int64_t a; // always used by func1, func2
int64_t b; // always used by func2
int64_t c; // always used by func1, func3
int64_t d; // always used by func2, func3
// end of 32-byte cache block if 32-byte aligned
int64_t e; // used by func4
int64_t f; // used by func5
int64_t g; // used by func6
int64_t h; // used by func7
}
```

If the structure is 32-byte aligned:

- an access to any of the hot members will bring all of the hot members into the cache
- calling `func1`, `func2`, or `func3` will bring `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` into the cache; if these are functions are called nearby in time, then the data will still be in cache

If the structure is 16-byte aligned but *not* 32-byte aligned (50% chance with 16-byte alignment):

- an access to `hot1` or `hot2` will bring 16-bytes of unrelated data located before `hot1` and not automatically load `hot3` and `hot4` into cache
- an access to `hot3` or `hot4` will bring in `a` and `b` into the cache (likely unnecessarily)
- a call to `func1` or `func2` is more likely to encounter cache hits for `a` and `b` since these would be in the same cache block as `hot3` and `hot4` but have a miss for `c` and `d` and less usefully bring `e` and `f` into the cache.
- a call to `func3` will less usefully bring `e` and `f` into the cache but not `a` and `b`

Even for a small structure, alignment can prevent the structure (or just the hot or accessed-nearby-in-time portions) from crossing cache block boundaries. E.g., aligning a 24-byte structure with 16-bytes of hot data to 16 bytes can guarantee that the hot data will always be in the same cache block.

Cache block alignment can also be used to guarantee that two locks (or other data elements that are accessed by different threads and written by at least one) do not share the same cache block. This avoids false sharing issues. (False sharing is when unrelated data used by different threads share a cache block. A write by one thread will remove that cache block from all other caches. If another thread writes to unrelated data in that block, it removes the block from the first thread's cache. For ISAs using linked-load/store-condition to set locks, this can cause the store-conditional to fail even though there was not an actual data conflict.)

Similar alignment considerations apply with respect to virtual memory page size (typically 4KiB). By guaranteeing that data accessed nearby in time are in a smaller number of pages, the cache storing translations of virtual memory addresses (the translation lookaside buffer [TLB]) will not have as much capacity pressure.

Alignment can also be used in object caches to reduce cache conflict misses, which occur when items have the same cache index. (Caches are typically indexed simply by a selection of some least significant bits. At each index a limited number of blocks, called a set, are available. If more blocks want to share an index than there are blocks in the set—the associativity or number of ways—, then one of the blocks in the set must be removed from the cache to make room.) A 2048-byte, fully aligned chunk of memory could hold 21 copies of the above structure with a 32-byte chunk of padding (which might be used for other purposes). This guarantees that hot members from different chunks will only have a 33.3% chance of using the same cache index. (Allocating in a chunk, even if not aligned, also guarantees that none of the 21 copies within a chunk will share a cache index.)

Large alignment can also be convenient in buffers since a simple bitwise `and` can produce the start address of the buffer or the number of bytes in the buffer.

Alignment can also be exploited to provide pointer compression (e.g., 64-byte alignment would allow a 32-bit pointer to address 256 GiB instead of 4 GiB at the cost of a 6-bit left shift when loading the pointer). Similarly, the least significant bits of a pointer to an aligned object can be used to store metadata, requiring an `and` to zero the bits before using the pointer.

Comment: I'm curious what kind of metadata does one store in a pointer?  That saves some space at the expense of performance.  When is this used in practice?

Comment: @Zboson I know SPARC implemented tagged addition (for LISP) to facilitate pointer tagging, but it used the load offset to "remove" the expected tag (and an alignment exception to catch unexpected values). Such metadata *might* have been used for garbage collection, but I just vaguely recall reading about using this trick. ARM AArch64 allows the 8 MSbits to be ignored so it can be used for metadata; I think Azul Systems' Vega provided 16 MSbits. This would probably be a good question for the [Computer Science SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Here are the alignments I have used:

```
SSE:           16 bytes
AVX:           32 bytes
cache-line:    64 bytes
page:        4096 bytes
```

SSE and AVX both offer load and store instructions which require alignment to 16 bytes for SSE or 32 bytes for AVX.  E.g.

```
SSE: _mm_load_ps() and _mm_store_ps()
AVX: _mm256_load_ps() and _mm256_store_ps()
```

However, they also offer instructions which don't require alignment:

```
SSE: _mm_loadu_ps() and _mm_storeu_ps()  
AVX: _mm256_loadu_ps() and _mm256_storeu_ps()
```

Before Nahelem the unaligned loads/store had a larger latency/throughput even on aligned memory then the instructions that required alignment.  However, since Nahelem they have the same latency/throughput on aligned memory which means there is no reason to use the load/store instructions which require alignment anymore.  That does NOT mean that aligned memory does not matter anymore.

If 16 or 32 bytes cross a cache line and these 16 or 32 bytes are loaded into a SSE/AVX register this can cause a stall so it can also help to align to a cache line.  In practice I usually align to 64 bytes.

On multi-socket systems with multiple processors sharing memory between the processors is slower than accessing the main memory of each processor.  For this reason it can help to make sure that memory is not split between a virtual page which is usually, but not not necessarily, 4096 bytes.